# How to pass static double array to (type**) function as parameter

Tags: c++

Well, i have function:

```
void func(char*[]);
```

Then, i have some array:

```
char[100][20] array;
```

Next try to call that function would cause a compilation error:

```
func(array);
```

so, what would your next possible actions may be?

Comment: You declaration of `array` is not a valid C++ variable declaration.

Comment: Use `std::array<std::array<char, 100>, 20>` or `std::array<std::string, 20>`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument declaration `char*[]` is an array of pointers, but you need to have it as a pointer to an array, i.e. `char(*)[]`.